# In reversible processes in dynamic equilibrium why do we only see the products and not the reactants?

Tags: equilibrium

If both forward and backward reaction rates are equal why is it that only the products are visible to a naked eye?

Answer (score 1):

Not really. It just depends on the reaction conditions. Consider the following reaction:
$$\ce{N2O4 <=> 2NO2}$$

Here’s a picture showing this equilibrium in action:
[image]
One of the reasons you can’t see the reactant here is because it is colourless, but this gives a pretty good example regarding visual equilibrium changes.

[this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/110256/what-does-the-reaction-of-hydrogen-and-iodine-to-hydrogen-iodide-look-like) is a good answer giving another example of a equilibrium that can be seen visually.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think so ?

As I have missed the other answer, this is just a complement to it.

In the equilibrium:

$$\ce{ 2 NO2 <=> N2O4}$$

both are reactants and products at the same time.

If you formally consider products on the right side, then you see by the naked eyes the red-brown reactant.

What is or is not seen depends solely on the properties and amount/concentration of the substance.